# Deployment of a rails 3.1 app fails with capistrano

Tags: capistrano, ruby-on-rails-3.1, aloha-editor

I try to deploy my rails 3.1 application with capistrano but it fails with following output:

```
rake aborted!

File name too long - /srv/good2go.ch/cookbook/releases/20110727063856/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Fsrv%2Fgood2go.ch%2Fcookbook%2Fshared%2Fbundle%2Fruby%2F1.9.1%2Fgems%2Faloha_rails-0.1.4%2Flib%2Fassets%2Fjavascripts%2Faloha%2Fplugins%2Fcom.gentics.aloha.plugins.HighlightEditables%2Fcss%2FHighlightEditables.css%3Asource20110727-2736-dx9guk.lock

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

It's this task who fails: RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Anyone an idea what it could be?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's because Sprockets is trying to compile your Javascript, or in this case the "aloha_rails" gem, into a single file and using the entire path to the script as the file name. Your OS doesn't support a file name that long. Don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that sprockets uses a somewhat quoted URL identifier to the gem. This can get very long.

This issue has been reported to the sprockets issue [tracker at github](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/138) and has been fixed by using a hexdigest  instead of the full URL in this [commit](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/commit/4a12801ec655e4c033dfad3c258e09d2ef79b671).

As of today, there has been no new (beta) release containing the fix. But you may use the sprocket version by pointing to github in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sprockets', :git => 'https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets.git'
```

Comment: Thus to keep you informed: Current sprockets gem on github do work. No extra Gemfile magic needed anymore:-) Drop gem version dependency in Gemfile, run _bundle_

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue when sprockets try to compile jquery from jquery-rails.

As a temporary solution, I copied and pasted the jquery files from jquery-rails into vendor of my application.

Comment: The deployment was successful but the aloha editor doesn't work as expected. On the first view some JS file are missing.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Should not be needed. While this is a possible workaround for a second, this should be fixed properly: Drop gem version dependency in Gemfile, run _bundle_